# use shiro with mvn jetty plugin

Tags: session, jetty, shiro, maven-jetty-plugin

I downloaded "[Spring MVC + Shiro + myBatis + JSR-303 Validation](http://bubba-h57.github.com/H57_Shiro/)" example from apache shiro doc page, and I want to run it with maven jetty plugin, So I open the pom.xml and put things like this

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.10</version>
                    <configuration>
                            <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                            <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
                            <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
                            <webAppConfig>
                            <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                            </webAppConfig>
                            <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                            <!-- <webAppSourceDirectory></webAppSourceDirectory> -->
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                            <execution>
                                    <id>start-jetty</id>
                                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                                    <goals>
                                            <goal>run</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                    <configuration>
                                            <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                                            <daemon>true</daemon>
                                    </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                    <id>stop-jetty</id>
                                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                                    <goals>
                                            <goal>stop</goal>
                                    </goals>
                            </execution>
                    </executions>
            </plugin>
```

After that I start the app use mvn jetty:run, I try to register a user in the example and I get an exception likes: 
"**java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroHttpSession cannot be cast to org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.AbstractSessionManager$SessionIf**", could anyone tell me why, and thx a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely ShiroHttpSession cannot be cast to AbstractSessionManager$SessionIf because it is not an instance of it.  This looks like a bug in Jetty.  I reproduced this, and then upgraded the jetty plugin to version 6.1.26 and the error went away.